# htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First time using RewriteRule, so I made

```
RewriteRule ^details/(.*)/(.*)$ /details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC]
```

but there are some problems for images, js, etc. For example the images doesn't work. And when I try to find the path `details/3367/images/coins-icon.png`

Is there a way to fix it?

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^details/(.*)/images/(.*)$ /images/$1
```

but that seems not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude existing files and directories from rewriting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Furthermore you should use `<base href>` or absolute url's (starting with a forward slash `/`) to prevent the browser from accessing the image files based on the relative url.

So when you're viewing the page `/details/456/` and there's an image `images/456/foo.jpg` on the page, the browser will search for `/details/456/images/456/foo.jpg`. To prevent this, use either `<base href>` or absolute url's (`/images/456/foo.jpg`).

Answer (score 0):

The rule you wrote is correct, but not what you want.

```
RewriteRule ^details/(.)/(.)$ /details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC]
```

The (.)'s in the pattern will match any single character and capture it. You probably want to capture multiple characters like this:

```
RewriteRule ^details/(.+?)/(.+?)$ /details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC]
```

The + is to let the compiler know that you want 1 or more matches, and the ? lets the compiler know to capture as less as possible characters (to prevent it from going further than the next /)